# How to generate a Tornado Diagram showing impact of different variables on output mean using 1000 sensitivity runs of a complex model?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, descriptive-statistics

How can I generate a Tornado diagram showing % impact of different variables on mean output? I have 1000 simulation runs of a complex model with multiple variables.

In addition a normal QCing of results, I have prepared output histogram to understand P10, 50 and 90 outcomes. I have also calculated Pearson's Coefficients to understand the degree to which different variables are impacting the output.

I have used this data to create a correlation tornado chart but would like to calculate % impact on mean output due to each variable. Kinda lost lost after this. I am doing all calculations in excel but proficient in Matlab too. Any ideas on how can I do that?

I can post the sample data set if required. Please let me know.

EDIT1: Definition of %Impact on Mean Output due to each variable - The impact of each variable (+ to -) on output should the other variables are at their base value. These extreme outputs due to a variable compared to mean outcome of the 1000 sensitivity runs can be used to calculate %Impact.

The problem is I have run the sensitivity using Latin-Hyper cube sampling across input variables, so all variables are changing all the times. Having said that, since I have enough sensitivity runs, I should be able to extract/calculate the impact on output if only one variable is changing and others are at their base value. There must be a statistical technique.

[image]

Comment: Anyone? There are quite a few tools that display their sensitivity results in tornedo charts. I just want to understand the workflow behind that.

Comment: You tell us you have calculated the Pearson's coefficients.  Your Tornado chart is a barplot of them.  What is there left to be done?  If you are asking about calculating "percent impact on mean," then please provide a definition of description of that quantity.

Comment: You are right. I have added the definition of %Impact on Mean in the original question. The order or correlation is not necessarily the order of '%impact on Mean output'. Hence the question.

Comment: Anyone please ?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers.